# how to implment chartkick dynamically with laravel and vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-8

i am trying to implement chartkick with laravel inside the vue component
i am trying to loop through all data inside the table using vue component

i have created an api which fetch all the data from the database but i am trying to loop through date and quantity using chartkick in vue js component
for example if the date is 01-05-2022 on this day the quantity is 14

```
<template>
    <div>
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-6" >
                 <line-chart :data="{'2021-01-01':data.quty,'2021-02-01':12,'2021-03-01':14}"
                 ></line-chart>

                </div>
         </div>
     </div>


    </div>
</template>
<script>

export default{
    data(){
        return{
            data:{},
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        axios.get('/data').then(response=>{
            this.data=response.data;

        })
    }
}
</script>
```

the documentation only shows the Static data but i want to pass dynamic data which i am fetching through api . i don't know how to use foreach loop inside the chartkick
can anyone guide me how i can loop my value and show them inside the component .
it is showing static data which is passed in this data object but how i can load api data and load it inside chart kick

```
<line-chart :data="{'2021-01-01':7,'2021-02-01':12,'2021-03-01':14}"
                 ></line-chart>
```

i am using vue js 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this one a shot and also make sure you have chartkick imported somewhere.

```js
<template>
    <div>
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-6" >
                 <line-chart :data="chartData"
                 ></line-chart>

                </div>
         </div>
     </div>


    </div>
</template>
<script>

export default{
    data(){
        return{
            chartData:{},
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        axios.get('/data').then(response=>{
            this.chartData=response.data;

        })
    }
}
</script>
```

For the data conversion, try

```js
    mounted(){
        axios.get('/data').then(response=>{
            let entries = {};
            response.data.forEach(val => {
                entries[val.date] = val.quty;
            })
            this.chartData=entries;
        })
    }
```

Comment: dear i am importing chart js it is also showing me the values which i have placed statically , but i want to show the values which i am fetching through api .

Comment: Like in my example, don't place them statically. Define it as `:data="chartData"` and follow the example.

Comment: i did tried the way u have told me by passchartData but it is not showing me date and quantity against that date .

Comment: [{"id":1,"date":"2022-05-01","quty":12},{"id":2,"date":"2022-05-02","quty":50},{"id":3,"date":"2022-05-03","quty":60},{"id":4,"date":"2022-05-04","quty":150}] my api is fetcihng data in this format and i am trying to show this data inside my component

Comment: I hope my change above makes more sense now.

Comment: man i can't thank u enough for ur help, u r amazing :)